# Rails cross cluster join with dynamic join condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, inner-join

So, I have multiple tables in multiple databases.

The user sends me database details, table names, columns to be selected and which column to use as condition for join. The structure is similar to:

```
[{ database, table_name, join_column_name }]
```

My current implementation is like this,

1. Connect to the first DB
2. Fetch all data from the table
3. Store the data in a result variable (PG::Result instance)
4. Extract all unique values in current join_column_name from result to a filter_values array
5. Connect to next database
6. Fetch all data where value of current join_column_name is in filter_values
7. Store the data to a local_result variable (PG::Result instance)
8. Simulate inner join on result and local_result objects, and store in result
9. Repeat from step 4

Also, **The join_column_name may or may not be an indexed column**

In step 8, I have to create a new PG::Result object, and store mapped data from result and local_result objects. How do I attain this?

Is there a better way to do this, without all these custom logic?
I've looked into `disable_joins: true`, but don't know if it is applicable in this case.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-set-up-a-foreign-data-wrapper-in-postgresql-ebec152827f3

Comment: Thanks for the link @max, it is an interesting read. In my case though, I need to be doing this from a rails context.

Comment: You asked for a better way. You absolutely use foreign data wrappers in Rails.

Comment: @max If it is possible in rails, please make an answer with a sample implementation or resource link. I'll mark it as the suitable answer.

Comment: Sample implementation of what? This is a very broard and diffuse question and you're not providing even a starting point for an answer. I'm not going to spend tons of time creating an example just to hear "but my actual case is like X". I doubt anyone else will either.